# Programmatically Fax from Internet form

Tags: forms, fax

I'm new to programming, and my only area of expertise is web design/simple development on platforms like wordpress/expression engine.  (Yea, you guys can laugh).

I have a new client who currently receives medical faxes through an online form (the user fills out a form concerning their prescriptions and once submitted, it faxes the info).

I'm completely redesigning their site, and I'm not sure how online faxing works.

Has anybody dealt with internet faxing?  How does it work?  Does/can it go through email?

And is it possible to send a fax through a form with javascript/php or route it through email?

Comment: Why don't you just go through the current app and see how the last guy did it?

Comment: Nobody's going to laugh at you; your question is well-phrased and polite, which puts you way ahead of a lot of people on this site.  And the question is relevant, which puts you far ahead of quite a few more!  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't pay for it! All you need is a modem on the server and a standard phone line. Then set up a fax print driver under your os (you can do it on windows and unix).

The unix way is mgetty/sendfax : http://mgetty.greenie.net/doc/mgetty_3.html#SEC3
The Windows way : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306657

There are other ways but unless you can't get a phone line you'd be mad to pay fees for it.

Comment: sigh.. voted down by an anonymous idiot. probably runs a fax service.

Comment: It's useful information, but at the same time, the rate on most fax <-> email bridges out there is so cheap, it's basically a minimal cost.  If you're a hobbyist, yeah, i'd agree to do it for free; but for business purposes, it's probably cheaper to pay for the service than to have to maintain a custom solution.  P.S.  I was not the downvoter; +1 to counteract, because your information IS useful.

Comment: At the same time, why buy/pay when you can develop/build?  Its something to add to the resume also..  You never know when a client asks for a very cheap/free method of faxing AND PAYS for that to be developed because he's not paying for faxing!  :-)

Comment: "why buy/pay when you can develop/build" - with that argument, SaaS services wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Would it not be helpful to look at how it is currently being done, that way you can learn a thing or two about the process before trying to go do it again? That way you can find if it is using any special libraries or techniques or services to send the fax and you can then either duplicate the code or use it as a template to get started on your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

All of what your asking is possible. I would recommend finding a service provider who can send the fax for you. They all have different interfaces requirements and pricing. I used to use DataOnCall which is now called [Fax.com](http://www.fax.com/)

They had a web service which we would post the document to be faxed plus additional information. They were a preety reasonable service. This was several years ago so I can't speak how they currently fair.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [eFax's SDK](http://www.efaxdeveloper.com/developer/twa/page/home). I haven't used it, but it looks like it might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send faxes via email through several services; [this link](http://www.savetz.com/fax/) seems to have some useful information.  I worked at a company previously that did this same sort of thing, and while I don't recall the exact service we used, most of them are very similar, and they work reasonably well.